# Filter column data with some keywords in each cell using paython pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Excel sheet so I am creating an Automation script which takes all the data containing some specific key words. Lets say in column C I have many names then I need to filter only those rows in which the data starts with term "John" with different surnames. If in Column C 1000 names are there and 100 names start with first name John with different surnames. So I want all the 100 name along with corresponding Column A, B and D. I am not able to filter out on column.

Comment: Please share sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) - try out this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 'John A', 3], [1, 2, 'John B', 3], [1, 2, 'Michael A', 3]]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df_new = df[df.C.str.startswith('John ')]
```

Comment: It is working. But I am facing another issue is that It is removing duplicate value. For example if 3 person has a name John smith it is printing only one John smith.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. If I execute the code provided, all rows containing "John" are displayed. 

Could you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use loc function. It will extract only data that has string named John in "C" column. Hope this will work.

```
df=df.loc[df['C'].str.contains('John')]
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding an explanation of why this addresses the question.

Comment: Thanks Karan for your help. It is working. But I am facing another issue is that It is removing duplicate value. For example if 3 person has a name John smith it is printing only one John smith.

Comment: Hi Raj, above code wont remove duplicates It will only select John named data if present in column C. can you please show me your code?